# Python Can't Find Module When I Downgrade from Python 3.12 to 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a working Python program on VSCode based on Python 3.12.1, but I need to downgrade to Python 3.11.7 in order to deploy my program as an Azure Function. When I downgrade to Python 3.11.7 though, my script fails to run and throws a ModuleNotFoundError - I can't figure out why switching my Python interpreter is causing this to break. All of my Python dependencies are in the same directory as my Python script, so I don't think it's an issue of my dependencies needing to move to a new place. Any ideas?

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\NewsArt.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openai import OpenAI
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\openai\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import types
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\openai\types\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .edit import Edit as Edit
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\openai\types\edit.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .._models import BaseModel
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\openai\_models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\pydantic\fields.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pydantic_core import PydanticUndefined
  File "c:\Users\marubins\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\NewsArt\pydantic_core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._pydantic_core import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
```

Comment: did you `python -m pip install pydantic-core`?

Comment: "All of my Python dependencies are in the same directory as my Python script" what does that mean?

Comment: Yes, I tried reinstalling pydantic-core - but that doesn't work.

Comment: When I say  my Python dependencies are in the same directory as my Python script, I mean I installed them with pip install <package> -t . to install them in my current directory vs at the system level.

Comment: in general, libraries installed for one minor version won't be compatible with another minor version

Answer (score 0):

before downgrade take a requrement.txt file and when you downgrading remove all the dependences and reinstall all. Maybe this is happening probably due to some compatibility issue.